# fact table : colums with same data and different meaning

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have fact table that contain data about foreign trade(import/export of goods), and i have 2 columns, named : coutryFrom and countryTo, the coutryFrom  is the country from where the goods is comming and countryTo is the destination of good.

Somethimes i will need to know to total value of exportation per countryTo to select the top 5 destination and sometimes i will need the same result but for importation by coutryFrom .

As as you know the list countries predefined, for ex FR France, IT Italy, UK, USA,...

I dont know if i should add the two countries in the fact table or only add country and do something to resolve this problem

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the country names directly to the fact table but instead make a `DIM_COUNTRY` dimension table with a `DIM_COUNRTY_ID` surrogate key and put the surrogate key into `COUNTRY_FROM_ID` and `COUNTRY_TO_ID` on the fact table. You can then alias the `DIM_COUNTRY` table in your query so that it can be joined to both `COUNTRY_FROM_ID` and `COUNTRY_TO_ID`.

Top 5 Country ***From***:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY F.AMOUNT) RANK
  , CF.COUNTRY_NAME
  , SUM(F.AMOUNT)
  FROM
    FACT_EXPORTS F
  , DIM_COUNTRY CT
  , DIM_COUNTRY CF
  WHERE 0=0
    AND F.COUNTRY_TO_ID   = CT.DIM_COUNTRY_ID
    AND F.COUNTRY_FROM_ID = CF.DIM_COUNTRY_ID
  GROUP BY
    CT.COUNTRY_NAME          
)
WHERE 
  RANK <= 5
ORDER BY 
  RANK
;
```

Top 5 Country ***To***:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY F.AMOUNT) RANK
  , CT.COUNTRY_NAME
  , SUM(F.AMOUNT)
  FROM
    FACT_EXPORTS F
  , DIM_COUNTRY CT
  , DIM_COUNTRY CF
  WHERE 0=0
    AND F.COUNTRY_TO_ID   = CT.DIM_COUNTRY_ID
    AND F.COUNTRY_FROM_ID = CF.DIM_COUNTRY_ID
  GROUP BY
    CT.COUNTRY_NAME          
)
WHERE 
  RANK <= 5
ORDER BY 
  RANK
;
```

Note that both of these queries will return more than 5 records if there is a tie. One final consideration would be whether or not you want to maintain different descriptive attributes for the originating countries and destination countries. Then you would need 2 separate dimensions DIM_COUNTRY_FROM and DIM_COUNTRY_TO. Either way you would still use surrogate keys instead of putting the country names into the fact table.